# Hide/show controls based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to show/hide a link in my web page based on the selected value of my drop down.

Here is my drop down and link

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOption" runat="server" Width="100px" onchange="templateVisbility()">
<asp:ListItem Value="Value1" Text="Value1" Selected="True"> </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Value2" Text="Value2"> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/myexcel.xlsx" Text="test template" />
```

`JavaScript` to hide/show the link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function templateVisbility() {
        var e = document.getElementById("ddlOption");
        var selectedval = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedval != 'Value1') {
            document.getElementById('Link1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('Link1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works as expected, but I feel I have done too much work for simple thing. Is there a better/simple approach to do this.

Comment: That looks pretty simple to me

Comment: @Liam - Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much you can do. You can just pass `this` to the function to reduce a single line:

```js
function templateVisbility(thatObj) {
  var selectedval = thatObj.options[thatObj.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedval != 'Value1') {
      document.getElementById('Link1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById('Link1').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="ddlOption" onchange="templateVisbility(this)">
  <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
  <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="Link1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="Link2">Link2</a>
```

Comment: This is hardly an improvement, it's different to what's in the question, but that's it. It's not going to make any kind of substantive difference to the running or readability of the code. I mean we could play code golf all day but ultimately what's in the question is fine.